# Fast Paging in mongodb how to show previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I am following this tutorial,
https://dzone.com/articles/fast-paging-with-mongodb

I subscribe to a publication using this code,

```
Meteor.subscribe('msgs', {"status":{$ne:"trashed"},"sender":{$ne:"You"}},
       {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 50},
       function(){
            if(typeof MessageDB.findOne() !== "undefined")
                msgId = MessageDB.findOne()._id;
});
```

So page 1 to page 2 to page 3 and so on is working.
But how can I go to previous page? 
For example:
User clicks button "next page >". It will display page 2. It is working but when user click button "< previous page" I am not successful in implementing a logic here.

I tried to store the last id as previous id too but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the tutorial, to retrieve page n, the code looks like:

```
db.users.find().skip(pagesize*(n-1)).limit(pagesize)
```

So when going to page n you should write somewhere that you are actually on page n, and going to previous page, you should run above function for `new_n = n-1`. For concrete implementation you should show, how you exactly get your data for a page.